# How to select the whole range of array formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an array formula in worksheet; how can I select the whole range occupied by this formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in any cell containing part of the array formula, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> then select `Special...` then select `Current array`.